# Error 0xc00d36bb when trying to play MKV files in Movies and TV

Tags: windows-10, matroska

[image: Error 0xc00d36bb]

Please help me solve this issue. The videos I'm trying to play have subtitles and dual audio.

Comment: have you been through the guidance provided in the link by Microsoft ?

Comment: yes, error 0xc00d36bb was not there @PeterH

Answer (score 0):

**error 0xc00d36bb** stands for:

> "Unexpected error occurred in the operation requested. Encoder (format) not supported"

my rough guess is that your MKV file is either HEVC (h265) or with higher bit depth (10, 12, 16) - or both

you may consider to have real media player: https://potplayer.daum.net/

Comment: I'm using VLC media player as an alternative to Movies & TV. I reason I posted this question was so I could go back to using Movies & TV - not for searching other media players :(

Comment: @iiScotchtape well, thats up to you what you will use at the end of a day... question was answered.

Comment: @MythicalCode_ https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers